# How to perform call with Asterisk and Skype

Tags: asterisk, skype

I am a newbie for Asterisk, so please be patient.

I would like to perform phone call originating by my application via Asterisk. I was recommended to use skype connection to terminate the call.

So, I installed AsteriskNow on VM with CentOs, created Skype Business account, got SIP ID and configured sip.conf and extensions.conf and explained here
http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=487451

Then I restarted asterisk service and checked log file. I did not see any error messages, so I hope that the configuration is accepted.

Now the question is: what do I have to do now? I want Asterisk to dial some phone number. It should arrive to skype that should forward the call to phone via VoIP gateway.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at my answer: [Asterisk click to call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194977/asterisk-click-to-call)

You can do similar thing. At first do test with your local VoIP clients. You can probably install 2 SIP soft phones, configure them in `sip.conf` and using CallFile test if you can make connection between them. If this work, then instead of using `Extension: SIP/test1` change it to valid dialable Skype for SIP "number".